# javafx update on startup

Tags: javafx, startup

I want to update the fxml file on startup , for example updating  a combobox that contain (1, 2, 3) will contain (1,2, 3, 4 etc) when I start the application.
the idea is that I want to read a text file and update the view from it when the application starts. but everytime I call or action on the main I got errors

*public class Myapp extends Application {*

```
@FXML private ComboBox aField;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    primaryStage.setTitle("HI");
    Pane myPane = (Pane)FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Gestion.fxml"));


    aField.getItems().addAll("1989");


    Scene myScene = new Scene(myPane);
    primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [javafx fxml is null outside initialize()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17634591/javafx-fxml-is-null-outside-initialize)

Comment: When ther is an error, it is always best to include the error description and stack trace in a question.